# How to turn ON USB Debugging in android phones on Locked Android Phones

Tags: android, usb-debugging

Is there any way to turn ON USB Debugging on locked Android Phones if I have got physical access to someone's mobile but the mobile locked.

Actually I want to install APK on Android Mobiles when I have physical access to mobiles (not my mobile) but locked. I have tried ADB Shell but that ADB shell also requires USB Debugging enabled.

How can I enable usb debugging?

Comment: I am curious, why do you want to do this? Allowing this would sound like a possible security risk.

Comment: its not possible you need to manually turn usb debugging on after phone is unlocked, Since it provides full access to system, this is a kind of security feature.

Comment: @UmarHussain if it's impossible then can you please tell me whats the suitable way to install android APK on someones mobile if I have physical access to that mobile but mobile screen is locked with disable usb debugging

Comment: Friend, did you solve it? I have the same problem.
I enrolled the device with QR code. For this reason, debugging by USB was not switched on.
My app is Device Admin on lock task and you don't know how it switches off or update this app.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are a company admin who needs to do this for a few employees? In that case you should really use a centralised tool like: XenMobile, etc....

There is no way to enable developer mode -> USB debugging remotely as far as I know, unless there is a Google guru around ... :)

Comment: Yeah @DanielSZ , scanerio is something like the company wants to keep track of their employees activities but without letting them know they are being tracked. So, what you suggest how can I install APK if I have physical access to their mobiles.

Comment: That sounds shady; have you made sure it's legal?

Comment: " the company wants to keep track of their employees activities but without letting them know they are being tracked" LOL love this statement. Just pray your employees never find out. There is no way to achieve what you want to do. You either ask the users to install that APK or subscribe their phones to XenMobile (I think its free up to a number of users) or a similar centralised mobile phone tracker. (it turns their mobiles into company mobiles -> locks them down). This also allows for remote wipe, tracking, etc. Sorry but there is no way to install any APK (especially through USB debugging)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. it's android security concern so, android os not allow user to transfer data in locked mobile phone. Android needs to unlock mobile phone once for transfer any data between mobile phone and other device.